# How do I get the current font/font size at cursor in NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

Clarification: First, cursor = the insertion point cursor, not the mouse cursor.

Ok, I would like to return the font / font size / font color wherever the cursor is in the NSTextView. I tried using `attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:`, but I failed because I got my variables all mixed up. I think it is what I need. Some example code would just be appreciated, `return`ing the font. I think it will work the same for font size/color, I'll just have to substitute `NSFontAttributeName` for something else, right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSFont *font = [textView.textStorage attribute:NSFontAttributeName atIndex:textView.selectedRange.location effectiveRange:nil];
```

Should work for all getting the name.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

`NSTextView` has a method `selectedRanges` which returns the current selection(s) - just one of zero-length if there is just an insertion point.

`NSTextView` also has a property `textStorage` which returns back the instance of `NSTextStorage` which holds the text. An `NSTextStorage` inherits from `NSMutableAttributedString`, which inherits from `NSAttributedString`, and that has methods to obtain the attributes of the text.

Combined those two and you have your answer.

HTH

Comment: What don't you understand? `selectedRanges` will tell you what is selected/where the cursor is. Using that information the methods available (by inheritance from `NSAttributedString`) on the `textStorage` property will tell you the attributes of the text. Font is one of the text attributes.

Comment: Sounds like you should take some time your yourself, recover, and then get back to this.

Comment: I have an idea in my head, but since my app is document based, how do I add NSTextViewDelegate? I can't find that. I think I need it.

Comment: ? That is a different question to finding the font. `NSTextView` has a `setDelegate:` method, have you considered that? You might want to look at the TextEdit sample code – Apple provide the full source, just search in the documentation.

Comment: I just couldn't find how. I got it now.

Comment: Can you show me some code because I don't understand still.

Comment: Please?! I really need this and I can find an answer anywhere

Comment: Have you read the description of `selectedRanges` and written code to call it? What did it return? Have you read the documentation for `NSAttributedString` and found its methods that return the attributes of the text at a given position? Have you tried calling any of them and seen what they return? You need to show what *you* are doing, maybe then someone can show you where you are going wrong.